# What is the difference, if any, between "divine providence" and "Providence" (with a capital p)?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, etymology, meaning-in-context, word-usage

[ODO](http://goo.gl/IYN59) defines providence as:

> **providence**: [mass noun]  1 the protective care of God or of nature as a spiritual
>   power: they found their trust in *divine providence* to be a source of
>   comfort
>
> (**Providence**) God or nature as providing protective care: I live out my
>   life as *Providence* decrees

So is there any substantial difference in meaning if I were to replace "divine providence" with "Providence". For instance, in the following context:

> Eugene acquired the chimpanzee, believing the chain of events
>   experienced by him to be *divine providence*. They did not make sense
>   otherwise. The chimpanzee was God’s emissary sent to him for a certain
>   purpose. If he ignored the chimpanzee, it would be like ignoring
>   *Providence*: impossible for a mere human to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a substantial difference between “God” and “the protective care of God”, so *divine providence* and *Providence* are not synonymous.

In your quoted passage, *divine providence* does not mean “the protective care of God”, but rather “provided/ordained by God” (see sense 5a in OED).

> **2.** In full ***providence of God*** (also ***nature, etc.***), ***divine providence.*** The foreknowing and protective care of God (or nature, etc.); divine direction, control, or guidance.
>
> **5. a.** An act or instance of divine intervention; an event or circumstance which indicates divine dispensation.
>
> **6. a.** Usu. in form **Providence.** God or nature as exercising prescient and beneficent power and direction.
>
> [OED updated 2007]

Comment: So "divine providence" means "God's protective care / divine dispensation" while "Providence" means "God".

Comment: Yes. There is a difference between *Providence* as a proper noun and *providence* as a common noun.